# How to list arecords available formats

Tags: sound, alsa

I built a tool that uses arecord, but now i noticed that it doesn't work on some computers, as the format isn't supported by that hardware, how can i see/list what formats thats supported?

Arecords man page says:

> -f --format=FORMAT
>    Sample format
>    Recognized sample formats are: S8 U8 S16_LE S16_BE U16_LE U16_BE S24_LE S24_BE U24_LE U24_BE S32_LE S32_BE U32_LE U32_BE FLOAT_LE FLOAT_BE FLOAT64_LE FLOAT64_BE IEC958_SUBFRAME_LE IEC958_SUBFRAME_BE MU_LAW  A_LAW  IMA_ADPCM  MPEG GSM SPECIAL S24_3LE S24_3BE U24_3LE U24_3BE S20_3LE S20_3BE U20_3LE U20_3BE S18_3LE S18_3BE U18_3LE
>    Some of these may not be available on selected hardware

Answer (score 1):

In alsa-utils 1.0.26, `arecord` has the option `--dump-hw-params` for this.

Comment: good to know, but the computers have 1.0.25, as thats whats shiped with ubuntu

Comment: The you'll have to [download](ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/utils/alsa-utils-1.0.26.tar.bz2) and compile it manually.